# DNS Configuration

Tags: networking, dns

I own a domain, let's say example.com
I want that domain to lead to my ddns hostname, so on my DNS I added CNAME record:
Alias *
name dynamic-dns.org.
That works perfectly.

Recently, I run into the need of having subdomain leading to another machine, so I added record "A"
Name: foo
Address: ip address of that machine.
But that configuration doesn't work. My guess is that there shouldn't be any wildcard in cname record... but what else should be there?

Comment: Subdomain has an "A" record? Why not use a "CNAME"? Target server has to be configured to recognize requests for "A" records. Which is why you should use CNAME, and then you don't have to worry about the IP changing on the target server.

Comment: Further, to prevent interesting problems and aggrevation, I generally never use wildcard DNS records.

Comment: BTW, One CAN have multiple A named records for a designated IP number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the symbole `@` as in `@.domain.com` instead of `*.domain.com` to represent your primary domain name. Then you'll be able to define subdomains normally.

Comment: I have actually used "www" instead of "@" for my dynamic dns host in cname, and "A" record guiding to point to an IP address. And now it works as it should.
Thank you for your help, Gregory!